# What is requirement coverage in testing?

Tags: testing, graph, graphwalker

I was looking at graphwalker which is a model-based testing tool. It creates a model like an oriented graph and uses a generator and a stop condition to walk on that graph, something like:

`random(edge_coverage(100))` //covers the graph random till all edges are selected (100%)

`random(vertex_coverage(100))` //covers the graph random till all vertices are selected (100%)

There is another stop condition called requirement_coverage: usage `random(requirement_coverage(100))`.

From the description on the website it says:

*requirement_coverage( an integer representing percentage of desired requirement coverage )*

*The stop criteria is a percentage number. When, during execution, the percentage of traversed requirements is reached, the test is stopped. If requirement is traversed more than one time, it still counts as 1, when calculating the percentage coverage.*

What exactly are those **traversed requirements**?

Answer (score 0):

This might be a little belated answer, but what I have found is:
https://github.com/GraphWalker/graphwalker-project/wiki/Requirements

Basically you can use `REQTAG` keyword on your vertices, mapping to some external requirement document reference (i.e. `REQTAG: requirement1`), and GraphWalker collects these requirements and applies the stop condition based on `random(requirement_coverage(x))`.

So in below example vertices are marked with the requirements tag, and using `random(requirement_coverage(50))` would result in stopping after visiting two vertices, etc...

[image: Example graph using reqtag]